# Genero una Table de manera dinámica pero se genera hacia un lado

Tags: javascript, html

Estoy generando una tabla dinámica a través de datos en firebase, el problema es que la tabla se genera hacia un lado y no hacia abajo. Lo que quiero es que los datos se vayan apilando hacia abajo.

Así es como lo estoy haciendo:

```
    var content = '';  
  firebase.database().ref().child(userpais).child(userciudad)
  .on('value', function(snapshot){
  if(snapshot.exists()){
    //console.log(snapshot.key)
    content ='<tr>';  
    snapshot.forEach(function(data){
        var val = data.val();

        content += '<td>' + data.key + '</td>';
        content += '<td>' + val.Tiempo + '</td>';
        content += '<td>' + val.Total + '</td>';

    });
    content +='</tr>';
    //console.log(content)
    $("#A_UsuariosListo").empty().html(content);
    }
    });
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

La idea es que se vea algo así:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

No sé por qué cuando trabajo con ul y li si se genera hacia abajo y con las tablas tr y td no se me están generando hacia abajo.

Espero puedan ayudarme, muchas gracias de antemano.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Veo que tienes fuera del ciclo el inicio y fin de la tabla. Deberia quedar asi.

```
snapshot.forEach(function(data){
    var val = data.val();
    content ='<tr>';  
    content += '<td>' + data.key + '</td>';
    content += '<td>' + val.Tiempo + '</td>';
    content += '<td>' + val.Total + '</td>';
    content +='</tr>';
});
```

Comment: Solucionado con tu respuesta @Oswaldo. Tuve que modificarlo muy poco, muchas gracias amigo.